# How to dim the background other than the view which was clicked

Tags: android, view, background, onclick

On click of a view in activity's layout, is it possible to dim the complete background of the activity other than that of the view?

I could find out the background dimming for popup window. But that doesn't work correctly with this requirement.

Comment: If you choose to use Shape Draw to Draw your view and then dim everything but that view then use this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584641/how-can-i-dim-the-backround-view-when-a-custom-view-is-displayed

If you are trying to use PopupWindow then try:

WindowManager or View Overlay.

Answer (score 0):

that is very hard work.
see this case. "A" root layout has 5 child views(a,b,c,d,e). "a" child view click, in case other 5 view changed background image(or alpha value). every view in onClickListener need that code.